# CodeIgniter Views

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok I have adopted a CodeIgniter Setup,

My route.php in config looks like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "development";
```

My development.php controller looks like this:

```
class Development extends Controller
{

function Development() {

parent::Controller();

}

public function Index() {

    $this->load->view('index');

}
function show() {

    $this->load->view('show');

}
}
```

When I go to the root folder, in my browser, it does load the index.php view, I want to make a link to show.php which is also in my Views dir. the URL I'm using is eg: my.server/test/codeigniter/ but when I go to my.server/test/codeigniter/show my show.php doesn't load. Am I doing this correctly?

I should mention I've tried public function show() also and it doesn't work, also I have no .htaccess file in the directory

Any advice would help!

Comment: my.server/test will point to index.php in Views directory and my.server/test/show will point to show.php in Views directory. So if you can't access /test/show try /test/index.php/show, because .htaccess not configured.

Comment: no htaccess file in the directory, http://myserver.net/test/codeigniter/ is what loads my index.php http://myserver.net/test/codeigniter/index.php/show doesn't load anything

Comment: myserver.net/test/codeigniter/index.php does load my views/index.php file though

Comment: did you try http://myserver.net/test/codeigniter/index.php/development/show ?

Comment: wow this did work thanks ken, :) move it to an answer and I shall mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two rules are enough in your `.htaccess` file:

```
# check if the requested resource is not an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# rewrite internally to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

`Mod_rewrite` and `AllowOverride All` assumed enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Ken Struys comment on your question is correct.  The default controller status you give a controller means that controller and the index function will load if you go to
`my.server/test`.

Other than that, you need to include `index.php/controller_name/function_name` to get to your controller functions.

Unless that is, you implement some fancy .htaccess url rewriting, which I can't help you with.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in routes.php as below:

$route['show']='development/show';